# Testing in Django 1.7 throws warning: RemovedInDjango18Warning

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-nose

When I do my tests with Django 1.7.1 it throws the next warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/_doctest.py:59:
RemovedInDjango18Warning: The django.test._doctest module is deprecated;
use the doctest module from the Python standard library instead.
RemovedInDjango18Warning)
```

I also tried adding in the settings.py file this line:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
```

But still throws the warning.

I write down the code from my test model file:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from myproject import tests, models


class TestModels(TestCase):

    def test_rol(self):
        rol = tests.create_rol()
        rol.save()

        self.assertTrue(isinstance(rol, models.Rol))
        self.assertEqual(rol.name, rol.__unicode__())
```

I have read the docs from the Django Web page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/overview/ but still can't get a solution.

I am using Django-nose.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem in the `django-nose` package (see [GitHub issue #149](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose/issues/149)).  It has been fixed in master, but there is no PyPI release for it yet.  For now, if you don't want to see the warning, you can point your `requirements.txt` file to the fixed version:

```
-e git://github.com/django-nose/django-nose.git@154b663097e8f3131fe5d1cdd8a8df2e388450ac#egg=django_nose
```

... instead of ...

```
django-nose==1.2
```

**Update: django-nose 1.3 has been released and contains this fix.**

Comment: pip install -e git... Is it?

Comment: @VíctorM yes, if you're just running a single command (not adding the dependency to `requirements.txt`), that is correct.

Comment: now that django-nose 1.3 is released, please use it like django-nose==1.3

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a `django-nose` issue: see [here](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose/issues/176).

So, just ignore it. Presumably it will be fixed before you're actually using Django 1.8.